# For loop skips one after every other iteration

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a list of HTML elements having class "black" (with some other classes). I want to convert the "black" to "white". I have written the following code.

```
var blacks = document.getElementsByClassName("black");
for (i = 0; i < blacks.length; i++)
    blacks[i].className = blacks[i].className.replace('black', 'white');
```

Interestingly, one element turns to white and one element is skipped until the end of elements. That is, elements with order of even numbers remain unchanged. What am I missing to convert all blacks?

Comment: Don't forget to declare "i" with `var`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the comment made about `blacks` being a live nodeList, you can avoid converting to an array, by simply decrementing through the loop:

```
var blacks = document.getElementsByClassName("black");
for (var i = blacks.length -1 ; i >= 0; --i) {
    blacks[i].className = blacks[i].className.replace('black', 'white');
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MXpys/1/).

Answer (score 8):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a [live `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList) that is automatically updated as you make changes to part of DOM it represents. You are treating it like a static list. You can do that by converting it to array:

```
var blacks = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("black"));
```

It just occurred to me that you could also:

```
var blacks = document.querySelectorAll(".black"); //NodeList but static
```