# JavaScript getElementByClassName + setAttribute not working

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname, setattribute

I would like to iterate over a html collection return by the getElementByClassName function.
I would like to use the setAttribute method to add "table-info" to the class attribute of the elements within the collection.

My problem is that not all elements are modified, to be specific, only the 1st element of the collection does not change its class. It is especially confusing for me that if I hardcode the for-loop, the result I wanted is still not achieved.
[image]

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" rel="stylesheet">
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"></script>

    <link href="/static/favicon.ico" rel="icon">

    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Country comparison: {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <thead>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Currency</th>
                    <th>GDP</th>
                    <th class="bar">Unenployment Rate</th>
                    <th class="bar">Inflation Rate</th>
                    <th class="bar">Interest Rate</th>
                    <th>Balance of Trade</th>
                    <th>Consumer Confidence</th>
                    <script>
                        myFunction()
                        function myFunction() {
                            const foo = document.getElementsByClassName("bar")
                            foo[0].setAttribute("class", "table-info");
                            foo[1].setAttribute("class", "table-info");
                            foo[2].setAttribute("class", "table-info");
                        }
                    </script>
                </thead>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried querySelectorAll() without success and also tried moving the script tag to other locations in without success.

My goal is to have the elements of the table receive their class before the page loads because Bootstrap will then color the fields of my table successfully.

Answer (score 1):

When you directly set the class attribute it overwrites any class (eg bar) that the element had.  Since getElementsByClassName returns a live list, removing `bar` alters the content of your foo variable, removing the entry for the element that formerly had bar.  If you just added the new class without removing bar this problem would stop.  Try

`foo[0].classList.add("table-info")`

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

```
myFunction()
function myFunction() {
  const foo = document.getElementsByClassName("bar")
  foo[0].setAttribute("class", "bar table-info");
  foo[1].setAttribute("class", "bar table-info");
  foo[2].setAttribute("class", "bar table-info");
}
```

Solution 2

```
myFunction()
function myFunction() {
  const foo = document.getElementsByClassName("bar")
  for(let f of foo) f.setAttribute("class", "bar table-info");
}
```

Solution 3

```
<thead>
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>Currency</th>
  <th>GDP</th>
  <th class="bar table-info">Unenployment Rate</th>
  <th class="bar table-info">Inflation Rate</th>
  <th class="bar table-info">Interest Rate</th>
  <th>Balance of Trade</th>
  <th>Consumer Confidence</th>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used queryselector. As the other answer says, this gets a live list and won't work. you should either cast the getelementbyclassname to an array or use queryselector.

Also here's an [explanation on why that happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316742/for-loop-skips-one-after-every-other-iteration)

Here's a working example with queryselector

```
<script>
      function myFunction() {
        var bars = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");
        for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
          bars[i].className = "table-info";
        }
      }
      myFunction()
    </script>
```